# HTML Not Rendering as Expected

Tags: css, asp.net

I am trying to replicate the 'Services Tab' section on [this](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/services.html) page, and [here](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-modern-business/blob/master/services.html) is the source code.

I want it to appear like this:

[image: screen1]

I have managed to get this to display:

[image: myScreen]

Below is my ASPX:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptGroupDescriptions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptGroupDescriptions_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptGroupDescriptions_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#service-<%#Eval("Group_Id") %>" data-toggle="tab"><%#Eval("Group_Name")%></a>
                            </li>           
                        </ul>

                        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="service-<%#Eval("Group_Id") %>"> 
                                <h4><%#Eval("Group_Name")%></h4>
                                <p><%#Eval("Group_Desc")%></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

And here is the sample code which I have used:

```
 <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                <li class="active"><a href="#service-one" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-tree"></i> Service One</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#service-two" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Service Two</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#service-three" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-support"></i> Service Three</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#service-four" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> Service Four</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="service-one">
                    <h4>Service One</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae repudiandae fugiat illo cupiditate excepturi esse officiis consectetur, laudantium qui voluptatem. Ad necessitatibus velit, accusantium expedita debitis impedit rerum totam id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quibusdam recusandae illum, nesciunt, architecto, saepe facere, voluptas eum incidunt dolores magni itaque autem neque velit in. At quia quaerat asperiores.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae repudiandae fugiat illo cupiditate excepturi esse officiis consectetur, laudantium qui voluptatem. Ad necessitatibus velit, accusantium expedita debitis impedit rerum totam id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quibusdam recusandae illum, nesciunt, architecto, saepe facere, voluptas eum incidunt dolores magni itaque autem neque velit in. At quia quaerat asperiores.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-two">
                    <h4>Service Two</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae repudiandae fugiat illo cupiditate excepturi esse officiis consectetur, laudantium qui voluptatem. Ad necessitatibus velit, accusantium expedita debitis impedit rerum totam id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quibusdam recusandae illum, nesciunt, architecto, saepe facere, voluptas eum incidunt dolores magni itaque autem neque velit in. At quia quaerat asperiores.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae repudiandae fugiat illo cupiditate excepturi esse officiis consectetur, laudantium qui voluptatem. Ad necessitatibus velit, accusantium expedita debitis impedit rerum totam id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quibusdam recusandae illum, nesciunt, architecto, saepe facere, voluptas eum incidunt dolores magni itaque autem neque velit in. At quia quaerat asperiores.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-three">
                    <h4>Service Three</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae repudiandae fugiat illo cupiditate excepturi esse officiis consectetur, laudantium qui voluptatem. Ad necessitatibus velit, accusantium expedita debitis impedit rerum totam id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quibusdam recusandae illum, nesciunt, architecto, saepe facere, voluptas eum incidunt dolores magni itaque autem neque velit in. At quia quaerat asperiores.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae repudiandae fugiat illo cupiditate excepturi esse officiis consectetur, laudantium qui voluptatem. Ad necessitatibus velit, accusantium expedita debitis impedit rerum totam id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quibusdam recusandae illum, nesciunt, architecto, saepe facere, voluptas eum incidunt dolores magni itaque autem neque velit in. At quia quaerat asperiores.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-four">
                    <h4>Service Four</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae repudiandae fugiat illo cupiditate excepturi esse officiis consectetur, laudantium qui voluptatem. Ad necessitatibus velit, accusantium expedita debitis impedit rerum totam id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quibusdam recusandae illum, nesciunt, architecto, saepe facere, voluptas eum incidunt dolores magni itaque autem neque velit in. At quia quaerat asperiores.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae repudiandae fugiat illo cupiditate excepturi esse officiis consectetur, laudantium qui voluptatem. Ad necessitatibus velit, accusantium expedita debitis impedit rerum totam id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quibusdam recusandae illum, nesciunt, architecto, saepe facere, voluptas eum incidunt dolores magni itaque autem neque velit in. At quia quaerat asperiores.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I assume that one problem may be the fact that I have not added class="Active" to the list item, but I couldn't because then each list item would have that class.

So here is my Code Behind code also:

```
//Trying to display group descriptions using repeater
    SqlConnection connGroupDesc;
    string connStringGroupDesc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
        "BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    connGroupDesc = new SqlConnection(connStringGroupDesc);
    SqlDataAdapter sdaGroupDesc = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Groups", connGroupDesc);
    DataTable dtGroupDesc = new DataTable();
    sdaGroupDesc.Fill(dtGroupDesc);
    rptGroupDescriptions.DataSource = dtGroupDesc;
    rptGroupDescriptions.DataBind();
```

Can anyone advise me how to improve my above code to go about this?

Comment: Are you using any `css` or `javascript`?  You don't mention them, but you'll need them to hook all this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator in your `ItemTemplate` which uses the `ItemIndex`

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "class=\"Active\"" : string.Empty %>>
```

This way only the first `<ul>` will have a `Active` class.